# How would I merge these 2 commands together?

Tags: bash, split, command

Input:

```
    FilePath    Filename    Probability ClassifierID    HectorFileType  LibmagicFileType
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 01d0cd964020a1f498c601f9801742c1    19  S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
/mnt/Hector/Data/benign/binary/benign-pete/ 0299a1771587043b232f760cbedbb5b7    0   S040PDFv02  data.pdf    PDF document
```

Trying to merge the 2 commands together, so it will split the file and inside the split files only show the file path and classifier ID ($1,$2)

```
awk '{ print >> $5.txt }' < output.txt

awk -v OFS="," 'NR>1 {print $1,$2}'
```

-thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one perhaps:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print $1 "," $2 >> $5 ".txt"}' < output.txt
```

Passing input to awk by `<` is also optional. You could pass the file just as an argument instead.

Comment: maybe -sed would delete rows in a file to?

Comment: @iOSecure Do you mean about not using `<`? It's simply `awk 'NR>1 {print $1 "," $2 >> $5 ".txt"}' output.txt`.